# Download streaming video on Android

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I'm working on a project that shows HLS videos. I handled this part with **ExoPlayer** but the problem is I have no idea how to download **HLS**.

I tried **Ffmpeg** but it increased the size of my app from *5M* to *26M*.
Is there any way to handle that?

Comment: [Exoplayer supports HLS](https://exoplayer.dev/supported-formats.html), does your server support it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Latest version of ExoPlayer supports downloading adaptive streams like HLS and DASH. Its quiet simple and straight forward approach.

Please visit the official documentation [here](https://exoplayer.dev/downloading-media.html)

Comment: It doesn't exist anymore. Has it been moved?

Answer (score 0):

TL:DR;
Use this library: https://github.com/waqas-334/HLS2MP4

Explanation:
HLS is just a text file containing links to segments at different bitrates or resolutions.
If you do `curl -i <URL>` on any HLS URL, you will get something like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, range
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Server,range
Content-Length: 1097
Content-Type: application/vnd.apple.mpegurl
Date: Sun, 26 Nov 2023 13:43:50 GMT
Etag: "usp-1FC67EA0"
Last-Modified: Mon, 21 Jun 2021 14:30:27 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.54 (Unix)
X-Usp: version=1.11.20 (26889)

#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:1
## Created with Unified Streaming Platform (version=1.11.20-26889)

# variants
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=493000,CODECS="mp4a.40.2,avc1.66.30",RESOLUTION=224x100,FRAME-RATE=24
tears-of-steel-audio_eng=64008-video_eng=401000.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=932000,CODECS="mp4a.40.2,avc1.66.30",RESOLUTION=448x200,FRAME-RATE=24
tears-of-steel-audio_eng=128002-video_eng=751000.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1197000,CODECS="mp4a.40.2,avc1.77.31",RESOLUTION=784x350,FRAME-RATE=24
tears-of-steel-audio_eng=128002-video_eng=1001000.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1727000,CODECS="mp4a.40.2,avc1.100.40",RESOLUTION=1680x750,FRAME-RATE=24,VIDEO-RANGE=SDR
tears-of-steel-audio_eng=128002-video_eng=1501000.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=2468000,CODECS="mp4a.40.2,avc1.100.40",RESOLUTION=1680x750,FRAME-RATE=24,VIDEO-RANGE=SDR
tears-of-steel-audio_eng=128002-video_eng=2200000.m3u8

# variants
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=68000,CODECS="mp4a.40.2"
tears-of-steel-audio_eng=64008.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=136000,CODECS="mp4a.40.2"
tears-of-steel-audio_eng=128002.m3u8
```

Now, you need to select the URL and append it to the base URL after removing the LAST part and you will get link to all the segments. Download them one by one in the same file and you will have the video downloaded.

Here, I explained in detail [how HLS works and how you can download it on Android](https://medium.com/towardsdev/downloading-hls-files-in-android-b5365196c57)